# Seeing double, triple sound in javascript audio, how to solve it?

Tags: javascript

```
**This function is in javascript:**

function quesfl(qsvalue) { 
sngno = qsvalue + ".wav";
var audiophile = new Audio();
audiophile.src = sngno;
   audiophile.play();
}

**html part:**


<input type="radio" name="qno" value="02" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">2
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="03" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">3
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="04" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">4
```

In the above java script code for audio, I have a variable 'sngno' for different src. However, when I change to different src, all the songs are playing, but I want only the one. While my web page is open, if I reload the page, each time the first selected song is played, but when i select other button for another song, both plays. Help please.

Comment: can you post more codes

Comment: This part is in html                                                                                         <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="qno" value="01" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">1  
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="02" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">2
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="03" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">3
<input type="radio" name="qno" value="04" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">4

Comment: Really interesting question. Basically this is happening for a very basic reason of OOP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

Try the following code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        audiophile = new Audio();
        function quesfl(qsvalue) { 
        sngno = qsvalue + ".wav";
        audiophile.src = sngno;
           audiophile.play();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="radio" name="qno" value="02" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">2
    <input type="radio" name="qno" value="03" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">3
    <input type="radio" name="qno" value="04" onClick="quesfl(this.value);">4
</body>
</html>
```

It is happening because each time you select a different radio button **a new `Audio object` is created** and gets played and hence all of the selected audio files get played ***simultaneously***. This got solved from the very basic concept of **Object Oriented Programming**.

Comment: Yes boss. It is working. Thank you sir. I wanted to know one more aspect whether this mode of audio play will work on most of the browser

Comment: The audio object is supported only in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I had success using this jquery sound library: https://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/sound/jquery.sound.js?r=5750

Answer (score 0):

Your `Audio` variable is inside the handler function, and every time it's called you create a new one & start it playing. Thus you end up with multiple, playing simultaneously.

Move the variable *outside* and only create it once.

```
var globalAudio = new Audio();

function playSong (songName) { 
    var songUrl = songName + ".wav";
    globalAudio.src = songUrl;
    globalAudio.play();
}
```

I've also improved the naming of your function & variables.. Hope this helps.